# do i need to include mod_aspnet45 and also install the windows_feature?

Tags: windows, iis, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm writing a cookbook for a server I need to enable some windows features on.

Do i need to do BOTH of the following?
`include_recipe iis::mod_aspnet45` and `windows_feature 'IIS-ASPNET45' action :install` or is only one or the other required?

the same question applies to other windows features for which i've found both a recipe on the `supermarket` and a matching `windows_feature` for.

Answer (score 0):

If we open up the [recipe file](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis/blob/master/recipes/mod_aspnet45.rb) we can see it does a little more than that, mostly related to dependencies of the `IIS-ASPNET45` feature. My windowsfu is weak so I don't know if it would do that automatically for you but I would assume that code is there for a reason.

Comment: So you're suggesting that the recipe inclusion would be more robust, and the `windows_feature :install` would be redundant? I prefer that answer, but want to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @coderanger's answer, and answer my own question - clicking into the recipe shows that the recipe itself runs the `:install` action on the following resources, so yes, running it again would be redundant.

Comment: Please don't copy code like that in to an answer. It only serves to get outdated and make someone else sad in a few months.